# use child variable in parent. java

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

Please how can I pass the variable tmp from cat to Animals that I will use it in my query

```
public interface Animals {
@Query(value = " SELECT * FROM #{#entityName} where  AND   name = :name nativeQuery = true)
T getvalue(@Param("name") string name);
}


public interface cat extends Animals{
string tmp = 'Domestic';
 }
```

Comment: You understand that they are interfaces, and that they don't have a child-parent relationship? you also understand that the code you posted won't compile? This has nothing to do with inheritance, since you don't use inheritance in your example. I recommend learning the basics first

Comment: public interface cat extends Animals @Stultuske to say that cat extends Animals

Comment: ok. they're still interfaces. you are inheriting type, not functionality. do you understand the difference? Also: if your parent class/interface knows it has child-classes, and knows details about it, your design is wrong.

Comment: @Stultuske Ah then you mean i can't use the tmp attribute in my class Animal?

Comment: you don't have a class Animal

Comment: i mean my interface animal @Stultuske sorry

Comment: do you understand the difference between classes and interfaces?

Comment: yes yes i know the difference @Stultuske im working on a project that uses interface that extends other interface.

Comment: yes, yet you seem to think that interfaces standard contain business logic. they don't. Neither should they.

Comment: so please how can i do? to use the variable **tmp** in my query?